# How can I call a JavaScript function in a callback of another function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is my code:

```
function User(){
   this.nickname='nickname';
} 
User.prototype.save=function(){
   dosomething();
};
User.prototype.add=function(){
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(positon){
        this.save();
   });
};
```

but `this.save()` is wrong, I want to call `save()` in another callback. I find this isn't pointing to the User, how can I call `save()` correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148451/help-this-is-confusing-me-in-javascript try this tread to understand context of this. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

`this` inside `getCurrentLocation` probably isn't what you think it is. Try:

```
User.prototype.add=function(){
  var self = this;
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(positon){
        self.save();
   });
};
```

Comment: I shouldn't feel like this is an accomplishment @p.s.w.g. ... but I'm interpreting it as one.

Comment: self is keyword in javascript and refers to window object.